# AngularJS vs. AppML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and AppML. I want to know which one is better and what is the difference between them because it seems the same to me as I have seen at W3Schools.

Answer (score 10):

1. AngularJs is a framework that binds your HTML(views) to JavaScript objects(models). It is a MVC framework, therefore, allows you to create properly architected and maintainable web applications.
   It reduces server load(PHP).
2. Companies like Google, Flipkart etc. are using it extensively.
3. Such frameworks(Backbone js, angularJs) allow to create Single Page Applications, thus making you websites more dynamic and quick.
   AngularJs is backed by Google!!
4. It tends to push the templating to the browser in order to free the server, which now only fetches data. As a result, client-side developers have greater control over the templates. It proves useful when you want to update one section of the website without refreshing the whole page. It is a great solution with which the code can be easily reused and maintained.
   Read on for more: https://www.angularjs.org/

**AppML**-Application Modelling Language

5. Earlier known as Application Markup Language, was similar to HTML/XML, but was abandoned by its creators in 2007(Source:  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appml)
   It is now developed and maintained by w3schools.com
6. It is not so famous though and not much information is available on the Internet. Don't know of any sites which even use it!

Comment: Good, ok, but there is so little information about AppML (the new one supported by W3Schools), I'm also trying to start with this one, but as khan xada wonder if there is any advantage to do so! For instance is angularjs capable of using data from JSON, XML, WebSQL as AppML claims. This advantage might be mainly for developing, but i think it's important.
Has AppML reduced decoupling compared to angularjs? Angular allows conditional and other logic inside HTML, whereas AppML appears to separate better MVC so: Model(json)-View(html+css)-Controller(javascript). Do you agree?

Comment: AppML is abandoned ! Angular 2 is much more than that!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, AppML is one step above abandonware. Its original developers basically gave it up, and W3Schools took it over in February 2015.

At this point (2/23/2017), searching for "AppML tutorial" in Google gives 43,000 results, but searching for "AngularJS tutorial" gives 848,000 results. This should give you some idea of the availability of support and documentation you can expect. AppML doesn't even have an English-language Wikipedia entry.

W3School's [history](https://www.w3schools.com/appml/appml_history.asp) page claims that it's used in "over 1000" web applications. (I haven't been able to find statistics on how many people are using AngularJS yet, but I assume that it's a *lot* higher than that).

To get back to the original question: in my opinion, AppML has "death spiral" written all over it. I'd recommend sticking with AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

**AppML** is something that works but never got trendy. It's what many of us already developed for home use, maybe a bit more, and it's a good starting point if you want to build your own framework with a simple templating engine. And it's small; `appml.js` is 75k in its full version, 35k when minified, and that's *all you need*, no dependencies, no npm install, no nothing.

Again, it's not a framework at all. But in most cases when people use Angular or React, they only use way less than what AppML can do; they don't use the full power, just the very basics like a repeated list with some fields of a data object. It's usually overkill. Maybe the closest big brother of AppML is VueJS, in all its simplicity and straightforward thinking.

Here's how we stand in 2021:

1. You rarely do more than what AppML is sufficient for,
2. You never get hired without at least one of Angular/React/Vue
3. Therefore you will never use AppML
4. It's still cool :)

Comment: AppML is still supported while AngularJS was abandoned with Google recommending upgrade to Angular 2+

Answer (score 1):

AppML is basicly the template engine part of AngularJS. Angular offers a lot more structures around it. If what you need is a template engine AppML should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As of January 1, 2022, Google no longer updates AngularJS to fix security, browser compatibility, or jQuery issues. The Angular team recommends upgrading to Angular (v2+) as the best path forward [Wikipedia article on AngularJS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS).

Now Appml maintained by W3Schoole and it provides tutorials and references.